# on appengine datastore I am getting exception errors but the transaction worked. so what is wrong?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

```
class registerPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        deviceID = cgi.escape(self.request.get('deviceID'))
        PNID = cgi.escape(self.request.get('PNID'))
        try:
            user = RegisteredUser.get_or_insert(deviceID)
            user.push_notification_ID = PNID
            try:
                user.put()
                self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "text/plain"
                self.response.set_status(201)
                logging.info("DeviceID = %s",newUser.key().name())
            except Timeout:
                logging.error("Timeout:%s unable to put user",deviceID)
            except TransactionFailedError:
                logging.error("TransactionFailedError:%s unable to put user",deviceID)
            except InternalError:
                logging.error("InternalError:%s unable to put user",deviceID)
        except:
            logging.error("%s unable to save Push Notification",deviceID)
            self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "text/plain"
            self.response.set_status(204)
```

I don't quite understand why i am getting an exception in the outer most scope i.e. when get_or_insert is called. the transaction was successful. i am pretty sure that it works but i can retrieve the entities and see that the new one was added. would someone know what is going on?

Comment: ok... so what error are you getting?

Comment: logging.error("%s unable to save Push Notification",deviceID) was executed. so the outer most block.

Comment: It'd be helpful if you posted the actual exception.

Comment: i figured it out. the problem is with the line. logging.info("DeviceID = %s",newUser.key().name()) and i also find out how to print out the exact exception. using except Exception as e:

Comment: Even if you don't handle logging at all, all exceptions will be written to the GAE logs. You've got a lot of unnecessary logging code in there, IMO. That huge code block could be written in 4 lines...

Comment: @TravisWebb actually i didn't see the error if i don't do except Exception as e: logging.exception(e)